Nifi Unit testing
I have created a Nifi flow, Which get input as files using get file processor and store the Store the records in a postgres DB, I have created the flow in nifi UI. I am beginner to nifi , Don't have much idea about TestRunner class.
can anyone guide how to test the flow in UI and how to check the same using testrunner.

in UI - just start processors one-by-one control/validate input and output, and finally check result... testrunner - are you asking about this: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mock/1.3.0/org/apache/nifi/util/TestRunner.html ?

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062240/how-can-apache-nifi-flow-be-tested for starters.
